# Downcasting a Box<dyn ForeignTrait> inside a struct?

Tags: rust

I'm having some dificulty wrapping my head around downcasting.

I have a struct which contains a Boxed trait, for example:

```rust
struct MyContainer {
    reader: Box<dyn std::io::Read>,
}
```

How could I downcast the `reader` to my known type?

Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=14b44be2412342d851d3c83fd9e080b0

Normally, I'd create a `as_any(&self)` on the trait which would result in a `&dyn Any` but this is a foreign trait which I do not own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your own trait which has both `Any` and `Read` as supertraits, then use that as the `dyn` type.

```rust
trait DowncastableRead: Read + Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}
impl<T: Read + Any> DowncastableRead for T {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

struct MyContainer {
    reader: Box<dyn DowncastableRead>,
}
```

With these changes, [your desired code will run](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f5c5b57b242fed637a7c30b0620efa36).

There's no way to avoid defining your own trait, because `dyn` requires specifying [exactly one non-auto trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html) (carries one vtable pointer), to get the functionality of `Read` and the functionality of `Any`, you need to define a trait that combines them (and defines a vtable that supports both sets of methods).

Comment: Thanks. This does solve my question. Out of curiosity is it possible to downcast if it's a `ForeignContainer` which contains a `Box<dyn ForeignTrait>`? In the case you don't control either.

Comment: @sharks No. The required information doesn't exist in that data structure and you can't do anything to cause the compiler to include it in a foreign container type.